# Consecutive UIAlertControllers - IOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I would like to present a consecutive *Alert Controllers* starting with an action from the first Alert Controller in Swift.

So the Scenario is this:

1) Alert_A is presented with 2 options:

- a) Present Alert_B also dismiss Alert_A after choosing this option
- b) Present Alert_C also dismiss Alert_A after choosing this option

2) Alert_B/Alert_C will have 2 options each:

- a) Action Alert_B/ Action Alert_C
- b) Cancel dismisses Alert_B/Alert_C

I've read in the Apple doc that it is not recommended to present an alert within an alert.

I also added a link to the hierarchy of Alerts:

[Alert Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/956Yc.jpg)

Comment: Can you post what code you've tried so far? Have you looked at the documentation for `UIAlertController`? Specifically the `UIAlertAction`? Here is a great tutorial on it: http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose", message: "Choose one of two alert options", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let Alert1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Alert1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert1", message: "You chose Alert1", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let Action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            /////////YOUR Action1////////
        }
        let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }

        alertController.addAction(Action1)
        alertController.addAction(CancelAction)


    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        let Alert2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Alert2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert2", message: "You chose Alert2", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let Action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            /////////YOUR Action2////////
        }
        let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }

        alertController.addAction(Action2)
        alertController.addAction(CancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }


            alertController.addAction(Alert1)
            alertController.addAction(Alert2)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Better Method:**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose", message: "Action1 or Action2?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let Action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        ///////Action1///////
    }
    let Action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        //////Action2///////
    }
    let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alertController.addAction(Action1)
    alertController.addAction(Action2)


      alertController.addAction(CancelAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Good @MikeMe. Good job